# How can i assign to the ConsoleKeyInfo

Tags: c#

How can i assign Enter key to the ConsoleKeyInfo ? (in C#)
Like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
if(read_mode)
{
   key = Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else
{
   (Ex. key = Enter)...
}
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.BackSpace) ....
else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_ConsoleKeyInfo__ctor_System_Char_System_ConsoleKey_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) structure using parameterized constructor

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
if(read_mode)
{
   key = Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else
{ 
    key =  new ConsoleKeyInfo((char)ConsoleKey.Enter, ConsoleKey.Enter, false, false, false);
}
...
```